# JavaScript Todo List - When I click 'edit' button, it doesn't show input to be able to change a todo

Tags: javascript

I'm building a todo list in vanilla JavaScript as a part of the exercise. I'm trying to get the 'edit' option to function properly. When I click the 'edit' button, the corresponding text input should be enabled, and auto-selected, then the user should be able to press 'enter' to submit changes.

The problem is that I cannot make Edit functional. Two of the other buttons are working well.

I know that there is similar question allready, and I have tried what was in that question, and still cannot get it done. Please help guys.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <h1>To-do List</h1>
    </header>

      <input type="text" id="addTodoTextInput" onkeyup="todoButtons.addTodo()" placeholder="Add new todo" maxlength="80" autofocus>

    <div>
      <button onclick="todoButtons.toggleAll()">Toggle All</button>
      <button onclick="todoButtons.deleteAll()">Delete All</button>
    </div>

      <ol>
      </ol>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

css

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee; /* Lightblue */
  font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: brown;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  min-width: 30%;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 50px black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 50px 3px black;
}

li button {
  float: right;
}

button {
  background-color: #bbb; /* Darkgrey */
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #d8d2d2; /* Grey */
  color: brown;
}

/* Input for adding new todos */
#addTodoTextInput {
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

js

```
var todoButtons = {
  todos: [],
  addTodo: function(e) {
    // When Enter is pressed, new todo is made
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      var addTodoTextInput = document.getElementById('addTodoTextInput');
      this.todos.push({
      todoText: addTodoTextInput.value,
      completed: false
    });
      // Reseting value after user input
      addTodoTextInput.value = '';
      todoView.displayTodos();
    }
  },
  changeTodo: function(position, newTodoText) {
        this.todos[position].todoText = newTodoText;
        todoView.displayTodos();
    },
  deleteTodo: function(position) {
    this.todos.splice(position, 1);
    todoView.displayTodos();
  },
  toggleCompleted: function (position) {
    var todo = this.todos[position];
    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
    todoView.displayTodos();
  },
  toggleAll: function() {
    var totalTodos = this.todos.length;
    var completedTodos = 0;

    // Checks for a number of completed todos
    this.todos.forEach(function(todo) {
      if (todo.completed === true) {
        completedTodos++;
      }
    });
    this.todos.forEach(function(todo) {
      // If all todos are true, they will be changed to false
      if (completedTodos === totalTodos) {
        todo.completed = false;
      }
      // Otherwise, they will be changed to true
      else {
        todo.completed = true;
      }
    });
    todoView.displayTodos();
  },
  deleteAll: function() {
    this.todos.splice(0, this.todos.length);
    todoView.displayTodos();
  }
};

// Function for displaying todos on the webpage
var todoView = {
  displayTodos: function() {
    var todosUl = document.querySelector('ol');
    todosUl.innerHTML = '';

    // Creating list element for every new todo
    for (var i = 0; i < todoButtons.todos.length; i++) {
      var todoLi = document.createElement('li');
      var todoLiText = document.createElement('input');
      todoLiText.type = "text";
      todoLiText.disabled = true;
      todoLiText.id = 'textInput';
      var todoTextWithCompletion = todoButtons.todos[i].todoText;

      if (todoButtons.todos[i].completed === true) {
        todoLi.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        todoLi.style.opacity = "0.4";
        todoLi.textContent = todoButtons.todoText + ' ';
      }
      else {
        todoLi.textContent = todoButtons.todoText + ' ';
      }
      todoLi.id = i;
      todoLiText.value = todoTextWithCompletion;
      todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton());
      todoLi.appendChild(this.createToggleButton());
      todoLi.appendChild(this.createEditButton());
      todoLi.appendChild(todoLiText);
      todosUl.appendChild(todoLi);
    };
  },
  // Method for creating Delete button for each todo
  createDeleteButton: function() {
    var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
    deleteButton.className = 'deleteButton';
    return deleteButton;
  },
  // Method for creating Toggle button for each todo
  createToggleButton: function() {
    var toggleButton = document.createElement('button');
    toggleButton.textContent = 'Toggle';
    toggleButton.className = 'toggleButton';
    return toggleButton;
  },
  // Method for creating Edit button for each todo
  createEditButton: function() {
    var editButton = document.createElement('button');
    editButton.textContent = 'Edit';
    editButton.className = 'editButton';
    return editButton;
  },
  // Event listeners gor the Delete, Edit and Toggle buttons
  setUpEventListeners: function() {
    var todosUl = document.querySelector('ol');
    todosUl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var position = event.target.parentNode.id;
      var elementClicked = event.target.className;

      if (elementClicked === 'deleteButton') {
        // Path to the ID of each created todo
        todoButtons.deleteTodo(parseInt(position));
      }
    });
    todosUl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var position = event.target.parentNode.id;
      var elementClicked = event.target.className;

      if (elementClicked === 'toggleButton') {
        todoButtons.toggleCompleted(parseInt(position));
      }
    });
    todosUl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            var position = event.target.parentNode.id;
      var elementClicked = event.target.className;

            if (elementClicked === 'edit') {
                var input = document.getElementById(position).childNodes[0];

                input.disabled = false;
                input.className = "activeTextInput";
        input.focus();
        input.select();

        input.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
                    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
                        var textInput = input.value;
                        input.disabled = true;
                        input.classList.remove("activeTextInput");
                        todoButtons.changeTodo(position, textInput);
                    };
                });
            };
        });
  }
};
// Starting event listeners when the app starts
todoView.setUpEventListeners();
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you are binding event listeners before elements are added to the DOM. The elements that are created after adding event listeners won't have those listeners. I would suggest that your add events after creating the buttons or keep the buttons there all the time, just show/hide them with css.

Comment: The buttons are created before listeners. I have 3 buttons: Delete all todos and Toggle all are working well, but i dont know how to show input upon clicking Edit button. Take a look at the code if you have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I looked at the code. The first problem is the condition:

`if (elementClicked === 'edit') {`

It should be:

`if (elementClicked === 'editButton') {`

The second problem was:

```
if (elementClicked === 'edit') {
                var input = document.getElementById(position).childNodes[0]; //this line

                input.disabled = false;
                input.className = "activeTextInput";
```

It should be `var input = document.getElementById(position).querySelector('input');` to get the correct element.

https://jsfiddle.net/nh9j6yw3/1/

Reason for "undefined" :
on line `todoLi.textContent = todoButtons.todoText + ' ';`
`todoButtons.todoText` is `undefined`.

Comment: Excelent Rupinder, you pointed correctly to the input, I didnt know how to do that, thank you. But my last problem is that when you add new todo, for each todo it says 'undefined'. If you go to 'todomvc' website, you will understand what I wanted. When I add todo, it should show just the name of the todo in the input. Do you know how to remove the 'undefined' that is showing?

Comment: Edited my answer. I suggest you learn to use chrome developer tools for debugging. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: I understand. I didnt use dev tools so often. I realy appreciate your help. That was the last piece I neederld. I will now study parts of the code in more detail.